# Linux: Reverse Sort files in directory and get second file

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to get the second file, when file contents sorted in reverse (desc order) and copy it to my local directory using `scp`

Here's what I got:

```
scp -r uname@host:./backups/dir1/$(ls -r | head -2| tail -1) /tmp/data_sync/dir1/
```

I still seem to copy all the files when I run this script. What am I missing? TIA.

Comment: Do you know what `-r` comes from ? Why do you use it ?

Comment: The one from `scp` :) (`scp -r`) + I don't understand what do you want to achieve. You want to `scp` a file which has its content sorted in reverse order ?

Comment: Ah!!! That recursively copied the files previously -> I'm trying to get rid of that.

Comment: I've rolled the edit back as the `scp -r` was part of the problem, and some of the answers refer to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$(...)` is being interpreted locally. If you want the commands to run on the remote, you'll need to use `ssh` and have the remote side use `scp` to copy files to your local system.

Since parsing `ls`'s output has a number of problems, I'll use `find` to accomplish the same thing as `ls`, telling it to use NUL between each filename rather than newline. `sort` sorts that list of filenames, and `sed -n 2p` prints the second element of the sorted list of filenames. `xargs` runs the `scp` command, inserting the filename as the first argument.

```
ssh uname@host "find ./backups/dir1/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '[^.]*' -print0 | \
     sort -r -z | sed -z -n 2p | \
     xargs -0 -I {} scp {} yourlocalhost:/tmp/data_sync/dir1/"
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question, your command is ok with just one specification:

- you first ran `scp -r` which recursively `scp`s your files which have theri content sorted in reverse order.

Try without `-r`:

`scp uname@host:./backups/dir1/$(ls -r | head -2 | tail -1) /tmp/data_sync/dir1/`

The basic syntax for `scp` is:

```
scp username@source:/location/to/file username@destination:/where/to/put
```

Don't forget that `-r`recursively copy entire directories. More, note that `scp` follows symbolic links encountered in the tree traversal.

Comment: I keep getting this though:
scp uname@host:./backups/dir1/ /tmp/data_sync/dir1/
scp: ./backups/dir1: not a regular file

Comment: Do you want to copy from remote to host or from host to remote ?

Comment: Remote Host to local directory

Comment: This is working for me: `scp root@ip:/tmp/test_script/$(ls -r | head -2 | tail -1) /tmp/`. Make sure that your files are on the remote server at the specified path